# Crash app in Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: java, android, error-handling, crash

I would like to crash my app on purpose after logging my own error. The Handler is registered in Application.onCreate():

```
// set global exception handler
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
@Override
public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, final Throwable ex) {
  // unregister
  Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(null);

  // do report ...

  // crash app -does not work, app is frozen
  if (ex instanceof RuntimeException)
    throw (RuntimeException) ex;
  throw new RuntimeException("Re-throw", ex);
}
```

However, my app freezes instead of crashing with a dialog. How can I crash the application as it would if I hadn't registered the handler?

Comment: It's seems that unregister should be outside anonymous class

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? When you "re-throw", you've eliminated any default exception handling, and you should expect your app to crash hard at that point.

Comment: @chrylis that is exactly what i want - but it does not crash, it freezes, not even ANR is showing.

Comment: @Flo I'm not sure that what you're seeing *isn't* a crash. Can you still use the home button to get out of the app? If so, just freezing up is exactly how I'd expect a hard-crashed Android process to behave. What does LogCat say?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This bit of code is never going to work.

An uncaught exception handler is called *after* a thread has terminated due to an exception that was not caught.  If you then attempt to re-throw the exception, there will be nothing else to catch it.

- If you want to have your re-thrown exception handled in the normal, you have to do the logging further up the stack.
- The only other option you have is to *explicitly* chain to another `UncaughtExceptionHandler`.

---

I *suspect* that the freeze is you are experiencing is a direct consequence of the current thread dying.

---

**FOLLOWUP:**

> ... is there some other way in Android to intercept exceptions at a global level, without using Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler?

AFAIK, no.

> Or how would the chaining look like?

Something like this:

```
public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, final Throwable ex) {
    // do report ...

    getSomeOtherHandler(...).uncaughtException(thread, ex);
}
```

Or, since ThreadGroup implements `UncaughtExceptionHandler`, ...

```
public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, final Throwable ex) {
    // do report ...

    thread.getThreadGoup().uncaughtException(thread, ex);
}
```

Basically, you just call some other handler.  It's not rocket science.

But note that you can't catch and recover from an exception in the "normal" way once you've landed in one of these handlers.

Comment: Thanks for this info - is there some other way in Android to intercept exceptions at a global level, without using `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`? Or how would the chaining look like?