# Handle unhandled exception and show alert

Tags: android

I am using the following code to display the user a dialog box but it's not working. The screen just vanishes on exception without showing the dialog. How can I make this code show a dialog with exception details and exit on pressing OK ?

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex)
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK",null);
                builder.setTitle("An error occured");
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        try { Thread.sleep(1000); }
                        catch (Exception ex) {}
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                });
                builder.setMessage(ex.getStackTrace().toString());
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In activity

```
public void Login_Click(View v)
{
    throw new RuntimeException("");
}
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: You have `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())` and `AlertDialog alert = builder.create();`, which one inflate your dialog?

Comment: An uncaught exception handler is called after a thread has terminated due to an exception that was not caught. If you then attempt to re-throw the exception, there will be nothing else to catch it. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440592/crash-app-in-thread-setdefaultuncaughtexceptionhandler

Comment: I am a new comer in this, don't know if you have to inflate it too. In normal Activities, the alert dialog pops up with no issue.

Comment: I am not throwing exception in onCreate

Comment: Post your Logcat here. Maybe someone will help you.